# What is a term for the "process of copying somebody's work/invention"?

Tags: phrases, analogy, single-word-requests

I need a phrase to mean *process of copying somebody's work* is in the context of industry/manufacturing. Is there a concise phrase with the meaning similar to "plagiarism" by a competitor in business (e.g. copy a car engine or design of the car)?  I am describing a situation where a competitor can benefit from the lack of R&D costs, and bring their product to market with a higher profit margin.

- `reproduction`
- `cloning`
- `replication`

I think "This was done to make the ***reproduction*** of their work by competitors more difficult." sounds not so bad and also doesn't lose the desired meaning.

The style is that of a technical register.

It seems that ***counterfeiting*** is too strict for the current sentence.

Perhaps I should restructure the sentence:

> Not least of all it was done to make the reproduction and distribution of their work (e.g. through reverse engineering of products and technological processes) by competitors more difficult (as the result of competing in manufacturing speed).

In this way both meanings are covered, though it is not a single word nor a phrase, rather enumeration of the senses: reproduction (clone/copy) and distribution (selling).

Comment: Reverse engineering, perhaps?

Comment: I thought about it, but this word emphasizes the process of disassembling and figuring out how does the stuff work, not the "reproducing" part of the meaning. But the word "reproduce" has not really the meaning of the "plagiarism"

Comment: I think there is a bigger barrier here.  You want one word to tell two stories.  They stole the idea and sold it.  I don't think a single word covers it in the sense you want to convey.

Comment: and again I think similar: already added the new variant with `reproduction` and `distribution` (see. update 3)

Comment: Do you mind if I suggest a few edits to clean up this post a bit?  It's getting a bit unwieldy.

Comment: @DavidM: I think now the meaning "plagiarism" was not really the best analogy. It is more about legal copy (e.g. without patents involved), but still the competitor could beat the prices on the market with less R&D costs invested in the same project.

Comment: I edited it down somewhat, I could have done more, but I didn't want to step upon your toes, too much.  Feel free to rollback.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13358/discussion-between-david-m-and-static)

Comment: @DavidM: the chat doesn't work for me (I should later look on the problem). Thank you for corrections!

Comment: No problem.  It was my pleasure to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Counterfeit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterfeit)** might fit. It implies the imitation of an original product.

> To counterfeit means to imitate something. Counterfeit products are fake replicas of the real product.
>
> Counterfeit products are often produced with the intent to take advantage of the superior value of the imitated product.
>
> The word counterfeit frequently describes both the forgeries of **currency** and **documents**, as well as the imitations of **clothing, handbags, shoes, pharmaceuticals, aviation and automobile parts, watches, electronics (both parts and finished products), software, works of art, toys, movies**.

[image]

---

From [International Trademark Association](http://www.inta.org/TrademarkBasics/FactSheets/Pages/Counterfeiting.aspx):

> **Counterfeiting** is the practice of manufacturing goods, often of inferior quality, and selling them under a brand name without the brand owner’s authorization.
>
> Anything that can be made can be counterfeited.

Answer (score 2):

The noun **[knockoff](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/knockoff)** means

> (slang) a copy or imitation; esp., an inexpensive copy, as of a fashionable clothing design (also ) ˈknock-ˌoff

The verb form **[knock off](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/knock-off)** means

> (US, slang) to make a knockoff of

This term can be applied to imitating product design or construction, as well as trademark infringement or counterfeiting.

The term **[rip-off](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/rip-off_1)** is sometimes also applied to imitiation, but its basic meaning is

> the act or an instance of stealing, cheating, exploiting, misrepresenting, etc.

Comment: my fault: I did not mention the style where the sentence is placed is rather technical, so slang doesn't really fit there. But still, thank you for the precise slang variant!

Answer (score 2):

*Counterfeiting* implies that you are passing off a copy as the original.

*Reproducing* is the process of copying itself, but does not imply the illicit sales angle.

**Intellectual property** (often abbreviated **IP**) is the set of ideas, manufacturing methods, etc. that go into making a product.
I think you are trying to say:  **Infringing upon intellectual property**  or **Patent infringement**

For a slightly less technical/legal usage:  **Intellectual property theft**

In the end, the crime is not *just* the production, but rather the theft of the idea behind the product.

[See here for a better definition of IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intellectual_property)

Given your updated sentence:

> This was done in an attempt to protect their intellectual property from the competition and prevent the loss of their advantage in the market.

Comment: "`... but does not imply the illicit sales angle.`" - precise remark (I think so)! 
`infringement` is too legal/law/juristical for the text

Comment: @static That is correct.  I can reproduce something without selling it.  Scientific studies are frequently reproduced to attempt to find similar findings.  The process is not only legal, but encouraged.

Comment: @static If you are writing for a technical journal or similar, IP *theft* may be the term you wish to use.  Although, *infringement* is a frequently used term in technical circles these days.

Comment: I would also ask colleagues to chose from all of the answers here. Maybe you are right about `infringement` variant. Anyway thank you for the discussion and help!

Comment: @static Take a look at my update.  The last sentence says what you wished to say in a smaller package.

Comment: @static I think you mean colleagues (co-workers of equal status).  Colleges are universities.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the connotations of illegality or underhandedness in *plagiarism* but still maintain that the work was not of the competitors' own design, I recommend *imitation*.  Because [*imitation*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/imitation) here means "the act or an instance of imitating," let us consider the the related verb *imitate*. [TFD cites AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/imitate) with

> 1. To use or follow as a model.
> 2. .
>
>    1. To copy the actions, appearance, mannerisms, or speech of; mimic: amused friends by imitating the teachers.
>    2. To copy or use the style of: brushwork that imitates Rembrandt.
> 3. To copy exactly; reproduce.

*Imitation* has even been used to describe copying that has been done as a compliment to its inventor, as in the phrase ["Imitation is the sincerest form of flattery"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Imitation+is+the+sincerest+form+of+flattery).

Example usage in the sentence you provided:

> This was done to make the ***imitation of*** their work by competitors more difficult.

Comment: I choose the `counterfeiting`, but it is rather subjective choice for the given text. I think imitating is also suitable, though it has a bit of behavioral aspect of reproducing meaning (in my opinion, based on the definitions: copy actions, mimic: imitating teachers)